# Count all max number value in difference tables sql

Tags: sql-server, join, count, sql-order-by, ssms

I got an error when I tried to solve this problem. First I need to count all values of 2 tables then I need in where condition get all max values.

My code:

```
Select *
FROM (
  select Operator.OperatoriausPavadinimas,
  (
    select count(*) 
    from Plan 
    where Plan.operatoriausID= Operator.operatoriausID
  ) as NumberOFPlans 
  from Operator 
)a
where a.NumberOFPlans=  Max(a.NumberOFPlans)
```

I get this error

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

I don't know how to solve this.

I need get this http://prntscr.com/p700w9

**Update 1**

Plan table contains of http://prntscr.com/p7055l values and 
Operator table contains of http://prntscr.com/p705k0 values.

Comment: As it is, your question is a bit unclear. Would you please edit your question to show sample data and expected output, as tabular text?

Comment: I think you are going to have to do a join to get the results you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for... an aggregate query that joins both tables and returns the record that has the maximum count?

I suspect that this might phrase as follows:

```
SELECT TOP(1) o.OperatoriausPavadinimas, COUNT(*)
FROM Operatorius o
INNER JOIN Planas p ON p.operatoriausID = o.operatoriausID
GROUP BY o.OperatoriausPavadinimas
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If you want to allow ties, you can use `TOP(1) WITH TIES`.

Comment: but if in data base will be more with max value? i need to get all with max value

Comment: @mausasu1234: this query will return just one record, with the `OperatoriausPavadinimase` that has the maximum amount of records across tables `Operatorius` and `Planas`. You should give it a try on your database to see what it returns.

Comment: I know, but in my date base are two  records who got the same max value.

Comment: To allow ties in the resultset, you can use `TOP(1) WITH TIES`

Comment: My query has to be dynamic, https://prnt.sc/p700w9, I have to find the max and search all operators with that max, I can select top(2), but if new Operator would be added with 9 plans, it should be top(3) and so on.

Comment: @mausasu1234: I do suspect that this query does what you expect. Please take the time to test the query against your data. If you are not getting the result that you expect, then please edit your question to add sample data and expected results to make what you are trying to achieve clearer. Afterwards we will be glad to help more!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top with ties`.  Your query is a bit hard to follow, but I think you want:

```
select top (1) with ties o.OperatoriausPavadinimas, count(*)
from plan p join
     operator o
     on p.operatoriausID = o.operatoriausID
group by o.OperatoriausPavadinimas
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: @GMB . . . Does yours have `with ties`?